# Using "one" in scientific work

Tags: appropriate

I'm currently writing my Bachelor's Thesis, and was wondering whether it is appropriate to use the term "one" in a context like this:

> since a couple of years, one can observe

or would it be better to write

> since a couple of years, it can be observed that

Thank you

Comment: Yes, *one* can be used, and is grammatical. It seems though that the sentence structure is incorrect. "One can observe that since a couple of years ..." not the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the answer given by @ElendilTheTall, but would like to add another variation.

The previous answer rightly says that the word "since" needs to be followed by a date (or other moment in time, e.g. "since the discovery of ..."; "since the death of ...".

On the other hand, if you do want to retain an expression like "a couple of years", you need to replace "since" by an alternative expression, such as:

> *For the past* couple of years, ...
>   *For the past* two years, ...

This then changes the tense that needs to be used in the following clause, which should be *past continuous*:

> For the past couple of years, one has been able to observe that ...
>   For the past couple of years, it has been observed that ...

In answer to your original question, Yes, either the *one* or the *it* format can be used, but my personal view is that the latter format would be better - and more common - in a scientific or academic paper.

Comment: "One can..." is, in my experience, both acceptable and common in scientific writing. See, for example, the 3,540,000 results for "one can" in [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=%22one+can%22).

Answer (score 0):

Before you consider the usage of 'one', you have to fix the sentence as a whole. 'Since' must be followed by a specific time or date, e.g.

> Since February 2013

If you are using 'Since', you have to then alter the tense of the next part to match it, i.e. it should be past tense.

I believe that 'one' should *not* be used in scientific or academic papers, but your college should have a style guide. Assuming I am correct, the best construction for this sentence would be something like:

> Since (date), it has been observed that...

Comment: `one` is perfectly acceptable in scientific writing. At least it is in my field, Biology.